# Links issue with Firefox

Tags: php, html, firefox, cross-browser

I have retrieve some data from database and added some links like

```php
<?php
echo "<a href='somelink'>" . $fetchedsomething . "</a>";
?>
```

Output in Firefox looks like this:

[image]

There is empty space within the underlined link whereas in Google Chrome it displays correctly.

Comment: I've removed PHP from tags. And you should post not PHP but HTML code in such a question. PHP has nothing to do here

Comment: Are you in any case using `border-bottom:1px solid;` and some value other than 0 for `padding-left`, respectively `padding-right`?

Comment: The code that you have here works fine and regular spaces wouldn't cause any difference between Firefox and Chrome. Please check the CSS styles that you apply to this link.

Comment: @knittl: I thought about this as well but Firefox and Chrome handle these styles the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to do some [trimming](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) before you display it. Like so:

```
<a href="somelink"><?=trim($fetchedsomething)?></a>
```

If that does not solve the issue, your problem most likely is in your CSS file.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your `$fetchedsomething` variable contains white spaces, use [`trim`](http://php.net/trim) to get rid of them. (Also make sure you escape your output properly)

```
<?php
echo "<a href='somelink'>" . htmlspecialchars(trim($fetchedsomething)) . "</a>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your variable $fetchedsomething has a leading and ending space. You should trim them if needed. Have look at the generated html code.

Add

```
echo "<a href='somelink'>my cool link</a>";
```

and I guess you don't have that extra spaces around that link.

Comment: I did, my variable does not have any empty spaces.

Comment: @UdoHeld: Firefox doesn't apply `text-decoration: underline` to spaces. There is something going on with CSS styles that the OP fails to mention.

Comment: I believe its an compability issue, does any one knows about it.